# jquery toggle method taking two functions as parameters

Tags: jquery

I saw a piece of code other day that looked something like this:

```
$("#tog").toggle( function(){ code goes here }, function(){ code goes here })
```

As far as I have seen the `toggle` method doesn't take two function callbacks as parameters. Any references to official documentation would be helpful.

Comment: it is an older version of toggle, which was supported upto version < 1.9... see http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#toggle-function-function-removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a method that binds a handler for the click on the matched elements:

> Bind two or more handlers to the matched elements, to be executed on
>   alternate clicks.

Note: This method signature was deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed in jQuery 1.9. jQuery also provides an animation method named .toggle() that toggles the visibility of elements. Whether the animation or the event method is fired depends on the set of arguments passed.

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Upgrade guide to 1.9: http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#toggle-function-function-removed

Answer (score 0):

Its old and deprecated. If you want that support in your code you should use `migrate.js`

Earlier `toggle` method took two functions as arguments. Each `function` fired on every alternate `click events` .